# XNA on VS 2010 crashes on debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

If I want to create a new XNA 4.0 project in Visual Basic C# 2010 and debug it VS2010 just stops working. I dont get an error message and it doesnt turn white and says *.exe has stopped working. Moving it doesnt work and the 3 upper left buttons every program has dont respond. Closing or minimizing it by the task bar just throws a windows beep sound at you.

When looking at the Task manager I can see that the project I debugged is opened in three processes. If I task kill VS 2010 by the task manager 2 of these 3 instances of the project remain AND CANT BE CLOSED BY THE TASK MANAGER (It's not a graphical bug they get displayed after restarting the task manager too)

Note: That only occurs when creating a NEW XNA project. Creating new normal VS projects works fine. Old XNA projects still can be debugged too.

I tried:
Uninstalling XNA 4.0 Refresh
Uninstalling XNA 3.1
Reinstalling XNA 4.0
Reinstalling VS 2010
(In that order)
None of the above worked...
I also searched for that problem on multiple forums but didn't get a useful answer.

What can I do? Or was something I described unclear? If so please ask.

Comment: XNA is old and not supported anymore. You might want to move to [MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net/) instead, which is almost exactly the same library, but with much more support and constantly updated. It can also run on VS2015 fine, you won't have to limit yourself to VS2010.. And since the codebase is almost the same, migrating a project from XNA to Monogame is also not very hard.

Comment: I tried Monogame already but had bid difficulties with the Content Pipeline...

Comment: Do you have a good tutorial of that?

Comment: Actually, you should install VS before XNA. You can also install XNA on VS 2012 and 2013 using Refresh. Did you try that?

Comment: I installed Refresh on VS 2013 and I get the exact same error as in VS 2010 :/